# How to build a ddeb package with cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, debian, debug-symbols

I am trying to build a dbgsym package with cmake and cannot find any help anywhere. I've seen [CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/cpack_gen/deb.html#variable:CPACK_DEBIAN_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE) but cannot use it in CMakeLists.txt since the version of CMake I am using does not have that.

I do have `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)`.

I want to be able to include debug symbols with the package.

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? Perhaps, you can upgrade?

Comment: @squareskittles version 3.8, unfortunately it is not possible to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

The following `CMakeLists.txt` creates a debug symbol package. I didn't check if it's usable in gdb, though.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

message( STATUS "Build type is " ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} )

project( demonstrator
        DESCRIPTION     "Demonstrator"
        VERSION         1.0.0
        LANGUAGES       CXX )

add_library( my_library SHARED )

target_sources( my_library
    PRIVATE     my_code.cpp )

target_include_directories( my_library
    PUBLIC      include )

set_target_properties ( my_library
    PROPERTIES
    PUBLIC_HEADER   "include/my_code.hpp" )

install(
    TARGETS          my_library
    ARCHIVE
        DESTINATION  lib
        COMPONENT    runtime
    LIBRARY
        DESTINATION  lib
        COMPONENT    runtime
    PUBLIC_HEADER
        DESTINATION  include
        COMPONENT    development
)

set( CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME                ${PROJECT_NAME} )
set( CPACK_PACKAGE_CONTACT             "Contact name" )
set( CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION             ${PROJECT_VERSION} )
set( CPACK_PACKAGE_DESCRIPTION_SUMMARY "Description" )

set( CPACK_GENERATOR                   DEB )
set( CPACK_DEB_COMPONENT_INSTALL       ON )
set( CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_DEPENDS      "" )
set( CPACK_DEBIAN_RUNTIME_DEBUGINFO_PACKAGE    ON )

include( CPack )
```

You might be interested in this [ticket regarding a bug in CMake](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21356) regarding debug symbol creation.